# RMI registry list names upon changes

Tags: java, rmi

I have a Java RMI registry where I bind objects. I want to print the list of names bound when objects are bound or unbound. I tried looking for an observer/observable methodology but did not find how to do this: as far as I know, it would imply modifying the registry object to notify upon changes. 
The only method I am thinking that works, is to periodically list the bound names, keep the list, and when it changes, print it. This feels more like a hack than a solution.

Is there any way to do this properly using notifications or similar mechanisms?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no other way to do this.